# Include two links in the same paragraph that launch different images in modal windows

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make different links in the same paragraph launch different images in the modal window, but when you click the second, it only shows the first image again.  Any advice on how to correct it?  I was trying to find a solution that didn't involve separating each modal into its own div (I would need to force each div to not break to a new line).  I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution out there...  Thanks!  Here are my javascript, css, and html.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

modal.addEventListener('click',function(){
this.style.display="none";
})

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

function launchModal(element) {;
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  modalImg.src = element.parentElement.children[1].src;
  modalImg.alt = this.alt;
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
img.responsive {
display:none;
  }

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 2000;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
}

/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  font-family: Arial;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>
Archie is a dog that likes to steal things.  If you are interested in seeing Archie, click on <a onclick="launchModal(this)" href="#">this link</a>
  <img class="responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/cQy7Yg.jpg">and a picture of him will pop up.
Now we have a new sentence with a different modal in the same paragraph.  Wellington is a dog that likes to smile and eat cupcakes.  If you are interested in seeing Wellington, click on <a onclick="launchModal(this)" href="#">this link</a>
  <img class="responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/sPhLIKY.jpg">and a picture of him will pop up.</p>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">x</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that both elements have the same parent so you will always select the same image using `parentElement.children[1]`.An idea is to include the image link as a data attribute inside the link itself and avoid extra elements.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

modal.addEventListener('click',function(){
this.style.display="none";
})

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

function launchModal(element) {
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  modalImg.src = element.getAttribute('data-src');
  modalImg.alt = element.getAttribute('data-alt');
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
div.lisa{
display:inline;
}

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 2000;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
}

/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  font-family: Arial;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>
Archie is a dog that likes to steal things.  If you are interested in seeing Archie, click on <a onclick="launchModal(this);return false;" data-alt="img1" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/cQy7Yg.jpg" href="#">this link</a> and a picture of him will pop up.
Wellington is a dog that likes to smile and eat cupcakes.  If you are interested in seeing Wellington, click on <a onclick="launchModal(this);return false;" data-alt="img2" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/sPhLIKY.jpg" href="#">this link</a>
 and a picture of him will pop up.</p>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">x</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>
```

In case you want to keep the `img` element you need to create a kind of relation between them and their respective `a` tag. Here is an example where I use ID:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

modal.addEventListener('click',function(){
this.style.display="none";
})

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

function launchModal(element) {;
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  modalImg.src = document.getElementById(element).src;
  modalImg.alt = document.getElementById(element).alt;
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
div.lisa{
display:inline;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
img.responsive {
 display:none;
}
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 2000;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
}

/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  font-family: Arial;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  right: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>
Archie is a dog that likes to steal things.  If you are interested in seeing Archie, click on <a onclick="launchModal('img1');return false;"  href="#">this link</a><img class="responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/cQy7Yg.jpg" alt="img1" id="img1"> and a picture of him will pop up.
Wellington is a dog that likes to smile and eat cupcakes.  If you are interested in seeing Wellington, click on <a onclick="launchModal('img2');return false;"  href="#">this link</a><img class="responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/sPhLIKY.jpg" alt="img2" id="img2">
 and a picture of him will pop up.</p>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">x</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!  The only issue I have left is that I realized that if I add content above this paragraph so that it's forced down on the page, clicking the modal will automatically scroll the user back to the top of the page.  Do you know what could be causing this, and how to prevent it?

Comment: @Nani220 it's because the default behavior of the links .. you should add `return false` (see my edited) also better use event listener ... i will edit later to include another code ;)